# jquery if statement and .each, if statement runs unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue where an if statement triggers unexpectedly. I'm creating a transition between two images on click. After the transition ends I add a class to the body so some content appears and disappears. I want to reverse the transition by adding a class to the body, then moving the image back into place.

However, when I run the following code (I've omitted the code that defines the offsets). The first transition works fine – running the code in the first if statement then adding class 'expand' to the body. But on the next click to transition back, the class 'expand' is removed from the body, the transition on the images is run, but then 'expand' is added back to the body (the first if statement gets run after the transitions happen).

How would I prevent the initial if statement from executing, and adding 'expand' back to the body, on the second click/transition?

Thanks for your help!

```
$('.picture-item').click(function(){

if (!$('body').hasClass('expand')) {
  var length = $('.match').length;

  $('.match').each(function(i) {
    // get the data value for the equivalent pictures 
    var pictureMatch = $(this).data('image');

    $(this).find('.picture-item-background').css({ '-webkit-transform':'translate('+offsetLeft+'px, '+offsetTop+'px) scale('+offsetScale+')'});
    if(length == i+1){
      $('.match').find('.picture-item-background').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
          $('body').addClass('expand');
      });
    } 
    i++;

  });  
}

if ($('body').hasClass('expand')) {        
  $('body').removeClass('expand');
  $('#minimized').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
    $('.picture-item-background').css({'-webkit-transform':'translate(0px,0px) scale(1)'});
  });
}

return false;
event.stopPropagation();  

});
```

Comment: I don't know that the `if` statement is your problem.  You've bound an event handler that you're not removing.  It's going to run each time the event completes successfully.  It's likely that when you complete the transition back the event fires and the class is added.

Comment: @asafreedman That sounds like what's happening! Could you explain a bit how I'd go about removing it?

Comment: You could try jQuery's `.one` method instead of `.on`.  The event handler fires at most one time and the removes itself.  [jQuery .one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: I've done a couple things which have resolved the issue, but it's still unclear to me exactly why it did. I separated the click event into 2 click events, in hopes I wouldn't erroneously trigger the first `if` statement. This still triggered adding the class "expand" back to the body. I then removed the redundant checks for `transitionend` (`webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd`) and this seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it but I don't there there was too much wrong with what you had.  There are a few different ways you could probably do what you want.  I'd still look into checking out jQuery's `.one` method, though.

Comment: @asafreedman thanks for your help. I tried using `.one` and still ran into the same issue until i removed  `webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd`. Perhaps I was implementing it wrong. I'm going to keep trying the feedback I get until I can get a better understanding of what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, it look like you simply need an `else` in your code:

```
$('.picture-item').click(function(){

  if (!$('body').hasClass('expand')) {
    // your code 
  } else {   // get rid of if ($('body').hasClass('expand')) {        
   // the rest of your code
  }
  return false;
  event.stopPropagation();  
});
```

That way only one section of the code will fire on each click. As of now, if it doesn't have the class you run the first section of code which adds the class.  The next section of the code will always fire because you have already added the class.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. are you saying if both `if` statements return false it will ignore the conditions of the `if` statement and run the first one it comes across?

Comment: The first thing you do is check if the body doesn't have a class of `expand`.  Then you do a whole bunch of stuff.  Then you check if it does have `expand`.  The second `if` seems to be the same as just using an `else` there instead.  Not sure if that is clearer or not....

Comment: i think that is clearer. however, if my second `if` statement is the same as an `else` statement, i don't think it would solve the issue? currently it seems that the code in both if statements are getting executed regardless of the body's class. wouldn't changing it to an `else` statement just have the same result? sorry if i'm misunderstanding...

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the `body` will always come out of your top loop with a class of `expand`.  Eventually, as you loop through the `.match` elements, one of these elements will meet all of your internal criteria.  When it does it adds the `expand` class.  Your second `if` statement will then always pass and run the second set of code.  By replacing the second `if` statement with an `else` either top set of code will run or the bottom set but not both.  I created a [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/j90vj66y/1/).  It won't work because there is no HTML but you can see the code.